# How to include diaeresis / trema in URL to query The Plant List website?

Tags: r, url, unicode, encoding

I query The Plant List website (http://www.theplantlist.org) from R, but this does not work if there is a diaeresis (ë) in the plant name.
Usually, searching for a plant species name, e.g. "Vaccinium acosta", correctly leads to the individual species page (in R and in Firefox) with the URL "http://www.theplantlist.org/tpl1.1/search?q=vaccinium+acosta".

How can I query the species page for "Vaccinium borneënse" using the species name in the URL (not the--unknown--record ID as in http://www.theplantlist.org/tpl1.1/record/tro-50262461)? Is this even possible for this website?

I tried, among others, the following, but they all lead to the overview page for the genus Vaccinium (containing many different species):

```
http://www.theplantlist.org/tpl1.1/search?q=vaccinium+borneënse
http://www.theplantlist.org/tpl1.1/search?q=Vaccinium+borneense
http://www.theplantlist.org/tpl1.1/search?q=Vaccinium+borne%C3%ABnse
http://www.theplantlist.org/tpl1.1/search?q=Vaccinium+borne&euml;nse
```

Ultimately, I want to read specific species pages for a list of species in R using read.csv:

```
read.csv("http://www.theplantlist.org/tpl1.1/search?q=vaccinium+acosta&csv=true")
```

Comment: What is wrong with data from `read.csv('http://www.theplantlist.org/tpl1.1/search?q=vaccinium+borneënse&csv=true')` ? Does it give unwanted rows ?

Comment: Yes, it gives unwanted rows, which is a problem within the larger function I am using this with. 
Giacomo's solution works great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use: `http://www.theplantlist.org/tpl1.1/search?q=Vaccinium+borne?nse`, as in the text in http://www.theplantlist.org/tpl1.1/search. You should just transcode it for every vocal with diaeresis.

IMHO this is an error of The Plant List. Diaeresis are not *valid* characters (for botanical nomenclature), but just used to help pronunciation, so the database should allow the second query.